# UIviewController not triggering its own delegate classes

Tags: ios, view, viewcontroller

I am not a regular user of Interface Builder. I am trying to create a new UIViewController Class with a `xib`. Lets say I am creating a controller named `myViewController` When I create that, XCode creates 3 files, `myViewController.h`, `myViewController.m` and `myViewController.xib` but the `xib` contains just a view. Wasn't it supposed to contain a viewController?

Anyway, I am initing that view controller with just `init` (yes, I have tried with `initWithNibName`) and the problem is that its own delegate methods like `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLoad` are not triggered on its own class.

Wasn't it supposed to have a delegate link between `myViewController.xib` and `myViewController.m`? what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "File's Owner" of your xib is your view controller. If you check the Identity Inspector when you have "File's Owner" selected, you'll see its custom class should be set to `myViewController`.

"File's Owner" is also what you connect your view controller's `IBOutlet`s and `IBAction`s to as well.

When you want to create an instance of your view controller programmatically, you use this method:

`-[UIViewController initWithNibName:bundle:]`

You can either pass in the name of your xib file to that method like this:

`[[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myViewController" bundle:nil]`

... or, if you pass in `nil` instead, it will default to using the xib that has a file name that matches your class name:

`[[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]`

If you wanted to use a different xib file that also had its "File's Owner" class set to `myViewController`, you would pass that xib file name instead:

`[[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourOtherXibFileName" bundle:nil]`

Comment: Ok, I did a initWithNibName:bundle but no delegate methods like  viewDidAppear, awakeFromNib or viewDidLoad of myViewController.m are triggered

Comment: Those methods will get called when the VC's view is added to the windows view hierarchy and so it will depend on how and where you're adding the VC to the view hierarchy

Comment: Added to the view hierarchy? I am adding the VC to a popover, the viewController is showing beautifully, all buttons, labels, etc,  but no methods are triggered on its own class.

Comment: (cont...) I have tried to present the VC directly without the popover and the same thing. The VC is shown but no method is triggered.

Comment: @RubberDuck Hmmm... Can we see your code that creates your VC and your code that creates and presents your popover controller? Also, I should ask: are storyboards involved in this in any way? It sounds like you're not actually creating an instance of your view controller subclass – you may instead be creating an instance of just a `UIViewController`.

Comment: the view controller is a standard one. Try this: new file > cocoa touch > viewcontroller... create Xib file. Then present that VC using self presentViewController... bla bla... in my case it will not trigger any viewDidLoad or whatever on its own class. I did no modification to that VC except adding a button and a label.

Comment: that was some Xcode crisis. I have deleted the whole class and xib, quit xcode, recreated the whole thing and it is now triggering. Thanks.

Comment: @RubberDuck Oh good! Yeah Xcode can be kinda buggy sometimes. Glad this helped.